# Deploy Web App on AWS

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a beginner on cloud providers, and I have a website to deploy. The website is made with PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript, and it uses an API developed on NodeJS to access a database.

Is there a way to deploy all of this (Inteface + NodeJS API) on one AWS Elastic Beanstalk application? Or should I deploy only the API on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and deploy the website's interface with other AWS solution, e.g. a static website on Amazon S3.

I'm really lost on so many solutions, can someone give me some tips on this scenario?

Comment: Your are using PHP for you website you cannot host that on S3 as the Php code will not execute there.

Comment: @error2007s thanks, I didn't know that. I guess I'll have to keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is you can deploy PHP application using Elastic Beanstalk and then apply edits to the configuration file of Elastic Beanstalk to Install Nodejs on the EC2 instance.

Or another solution is you can setup you PHP and Node application on a standalone EC2 instance and after everything is set you can create the AMI of that instance and use it in Elastic beanstalk .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html